# zend framework and doctrine (getters and setters)

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, getter-setter

Is it possible to use doctrine on existing entity models like:

```
class user{
protected $_id;
protected $_name;

public function set_id($_id){}
public function get_id(){}
public function set_name($_name){}
public function get_name(){}
}
```

or to generate or use models with hard-coded getters and setters.

I dont want to use

```
$user->name
$user['name'] 
$user->get('name')
```

can this be done with doctrine?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all Versions up to Doctrine 1.2:
Your entity models class needs to extend the Doctrine_Record class.

The definition of the model fields needs to be done the "doctrine way" too.
See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models

example:

> public function setTableDefinition()
>      {
>
> ```
>    $this->hasColumn('username', 'string', 255);
>    $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 255);
> ```
>
> }

If you want to use your own custom hard coded setters/getters you can override the magic getters/setters. 
See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/introduction-to-models
example:

> class User extends BaseUser {
>
> ```
> public function setPassword($password)
> {
>     return $this->_set('password', md5($password));
> }
> ```
>
> }

One last remark/question: Using the magic setter/getter methods is good practise.. You should only use custom methods, if you need to manipulate the data in some way.

Comment: I glanced in documentation for doctrune 2.0 and I found this 
$user = new CmsUser;
$user->setStatus('user');
$user->setUsername('user' . $i);
$user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);